# Set of all functions of $\mathbb N$ $\to$ $\mathbb R$

Tags: cardinals

I got a question about the cardinal of set of all function of $\mathbb N$ $\to$ $\mathbb R$.
I think that the cardinal number of the set is C because the range of all function is R which the cardinal number of it is C, but I dont knowhow to prove it.

Thank you,

Comment: Given your reasoning, what would be the cardinality of the set of functions $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: These seem to be related: [Bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb {R^N}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243590/bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-rn) and [Bijection between $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb R$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/352413/bijection-between-mathbb-r-mathbb-n-and-mathbb-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

Let $B$ be the set of binary sequences. I take it as known that $B\sim \mathbb R,$ where $\sim$ means "same cardinality". Then your set $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N} \sim B^{\mathbb N}.$

An element of $B^{\mathbb N}$ can be viewed as an infinite matrix $(a_{mn}),$ with $m$ denoting the row, and $n$ denoting the column. We can associate with this matrix the binary sequence $a_{11},\,a_{21},\,a_{12},\, a_{31},\,a_{22},\,a_{13}, \dots,$ where we've used Cantor's trick of moving along the cross diagonals of the matrix. This establishes a 1-1 correspondence between $B^{\mathbb N}$ and $B.$ Thus $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N} \sim \mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that it's $\mathfrak{c}$, but the cardinality of the range isn't enough to conclude that. The most straightforward way to prove a question of cardinality is to construct a bijection; a good shortcut to this is to use Cantor-Bernstein and construct two injections.

The first is easy: for each $r \in \mathbb{R}$, the constant function $f(n) = r$ is a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This gives us an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ into the set of functions.

The second is trickier, but not too much so: Given a function $f$, take the binary expansions of the various $f(n)$ and "interleave" them to form a single number with all the digits of the $f(n)$ in it. I won't get into specifics, but think about the proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality. That gives you a single real corresponding to each function, so we have an injection from the set of functions into $\mathbb{R}$.

In general, when dealing with questions of cardinality, you should *always* be thinking about bijections. If the word "bijection" does not appear in your thought process, then your solution is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: about the first stage, the constant function is a function in the set or a function on the set?

Comment: @Omri It's a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Which could it be?