# Bijection between $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It must be posted somewhere, but I can't find it. I've been working on it for a while too without getting anywhere. Does there exist a bijection between $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$? Is it possible to give an explicit bijection?

**NOTE**: This question is **not** a duplicate of the link suggested. Please see comments for further detail.

Comment: Yes, there is a isomorphism as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Paul S. The sentences before the question hint that you're looking for a bijection rather than just wanting to know if a bijection exists. What exactly do you want? And I suggest you clarify this fast, before it gets closed as a duplicate and it actually isn't (if that's the case).

Comment: @GitGud Ok I just read the link that Zev Chonoles posted. I see that they prove a bijection exist, but don't show a bijection. Is it possible to show a bijection?

Comment: Yes, Paul S., they do show a bijection there.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes, but the question itself is not a duplicate. I know you're not saying it is, I'm just pointing it out.

Comment: @dfeuer Don't they show injections in each direction, and then invoke the Schroeder–Bernstein theorem?

Comment: @PaulS. People are still closing this question as a duplicate. I suggest you type in **bold** that it isn't.

Comment: @PaulS.: yes, and (the standard proof of) Schroeder-Bernstein then gives you an explicit bijection.

Comment: I believe it should be possible to get more explicit than that, but it will require a lot of care about sign encoding.

Comment: While it might not be a duplicate of the posts indicated, it can be done using the methods of [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/243590/49437).