# Bijective function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I know that $\Bbb R$ has the same cardinality as $\Bbb R^2$, but can someone give me a bijective or even just a surjective function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243590/513123

Comment: an example is to take a given real number in decimal notation and then split the notation to get two decimal representation.

Comment: @RezaHabibi You have to be a bit careful, though, since some reals have two different decimal representations.