# is there a bijection for $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$?

Tags: relations

I imagine no since the dimensions do not match

but they have the same cardinality $|\mathbb R |= |\mathbb C|$?

Comment: If the cardinalities are the same then there **must** be a bijection by definition.

Comment: Maybe something with bit shuffling - choose every other bit for $R \to C$, and interlace the bits for $C \to R$. Making it 1-to-1 seems challenging.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking this question? For example, the **very first google hit** for the query "bijection r to c" is [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243590/bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-rn). (-1)

Comment: I did do research but the results didn't match. I wanted R->C (which is isomorphic to R^2).

Comment: How you are claiming $|\mathbb{R}|=|\mathbb{C}|$? The cardinality is defined by bijection between two sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a bijection as sets, the answer is yes.  That’s exactly what it means for two sets to have the same cardinality.  If you’re looking for a bijection that preserves some structure, that will depend on precisely what you’re trying to preserve but the answer is very probably no.