# Does a bijective function $f:\Bbb{R^n}\rightarrow\Bbb{R} , n\in\Bbb{N}/\{1\}$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, proof-explanation

I have noticed that in order to describe 3-dimensional space you need at least three variables in every Koordinate-System. My question is whether it is possible to assign every single point in n-dimensional space a unique number - in other words whether any bijective function $f:\Bbb{R^n}\rightarrow\Bbb{R} , n\in\Bbb{N}/\{1\}$ exists. If $f$ does exist - what would it look like - and if it doesnt - how would you prove it?

Comment: basically both spaces have the same cardinal

Comment: Remember to use the notation $\backslash$ (in LaTeX \backslash) when you are referring to complement sets.

Comment: Such a bijection exists.  However if you require also that it be continuous, then it does not exist.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb {R^N}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243590/bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-rn)

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

A bijection $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ that **almost** works is obtained by intertwining the decimals.  For real numbers $a,b$ written in decimal as
\begin{align}
a &= \cdots a_{-2} a_{-1} a_0 . a_1 a_2 a_3 \cdots
\\
b &= \cdots b_{-2} b_{-1} b_0 . b_1 b_2 b_3 \cdots
\end{align}
where all but finitely many digits to the left of the decimal are zero, let
$$
f(a,b) = \cdots a_{-2} b_{-2}a_{-1}b_{-1} a_0 b_0. a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2 a_3 b_3\cdots
$$
I say it **almost works** because there is a problem involving real numbers with two different decimal expansions, like $1 = 0.999\cdots$.  That problem can be fixed, but it is complicated to do it, so I will not do it here.  (You can see, instead, the many duplicates of this question.)

As Kenta notes, this also doesn't work because of negative numbers.

Comment: You also have to deal with negative numbers