# $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces such that $\dim V > \dim W$, then $T:V\longrightarrow W$ can't be Injective.

Tags: linear-algebra

"Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces such that $\dim V > \dim W$ and let $T:V\longrightarrow W$ be a function between $V$ and $W$. If this is the case then $T$ can't be injective".

I know this statement is true if T is a linear map, but is it also true for any function $T$, linear or not?

surjective

Comment: Think the inequality is wrong there

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry I made a mistake while writing the statement. I already edited it

Comment: No, it doesn't **have** have to be surjective. What about $T\colon\Bbb R^2\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ defined by $T(x,y)=0$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm so sorry... I mistook the concepts of injectivity and Surjectivity...

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Now is right, sorry once again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(answer to version 2 of the question)*

As stated, it is not true, even for linear maps. For instance take $V=\mathbb R^2$, $W=\mathbb R$, and $T(x,y)=0$.

*(answer to version 3 of the question)*

No. There [exist bijections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243590/bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-rn) between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R$, for instance.

Comment: I'm sorry. I mistook the concepts of injectivity and Surjectivity.

Answer (score 0):

No, of course not. For example, there is a bijection

$$\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$$