# Proof checking - $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \sim \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N})$ - Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, cardinals

I need to prove that:

$$\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \sim \mathcal{P}( \mathbb{N})$$

We know that
1. $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \sim \mathbb{N}$
2. And that $A^{B^C} \sim A^{B \times C}$

And so I start the proof:

I start by proving that $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \sim \mathbb{R}$ by:

We know that $\mathbb{R} \sim \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \sim 2^{\mathbb{N}}$
 (Because $| \mathbb{R} | = \aleph$ and $|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})| = |2^{\mathbb{N}}| = 2^{\aleph_0})$

And so:  $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} \sim (2^{\mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{N}}$

And by #2 above we know that $(2^{\mathbb{N}})^{\mathbb{N}} \sim 2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}}$
by #1 we know that:
$2^{\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}} \sim 2^{\mathbb{N}} \sim \mathbb{R} \sim \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$

So we are done.

I am completely unsure if it's true or not, I would like to get a proof review from you, I will be so thankful..

Thank you have a great day!

Comment: Are you sure 2 shouldn't be $(A^B)^C=A^{B\times C}$?

Comment: @J.G. In the assignment it is without parenthesis, does it really hurt the proof? :( I am now scared that it breaks my proof..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. But we can prove something stronger if we [use a third fact for inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem): any $\kappa$ with $2\le\kappa\le2^{\aleph_0}$ satisfies$$2^{\aleph_0}\le\kappa^{\aleph_0}\le(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0^2}=2^{\aleph_0}\implies\kappa^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.$$Your proof strategy already handles the case $\kappa=2^{\aleph_0}$ and then implies the more general case, as we can show $\kappa_1\le\kappa_2\implies\kappa_1^\lambda\le\kappa_2^\lambda$. However, you'll see the above argument in inequalities in many sources, as it doesn't require checking a special case first.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it mandatory to prove something stronger or my proof holds for $R^N \sim P(N)$ ?

Comment: @SendHelp No, you don't have to prove more than you were asked to. I'm just providing more context than "yes, it works". (Answers have to be a certain length anyway.) I hope it was useful.

Comment: Thank you very very much!!