# Representing a matrix as a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Is there a way to represent a matrix as a scalar without losing information? I know that I can use something as the Frobenius Norm, but that does not account for change in element positions. For example:

The F norm of the (1x3) matrix (2, 1, 0) is equal to the F norm of a matrix like (1, 2, 0). But the matrices are different. So is there a way to represent a matrix by a scalar and also detect these position changes?

UPDATE:
My practical problem here is I have a measurement process that outputs two matrices for a specific measurement. Both are square, symmetrical and integer matrices.

First one looks like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0
```

Second one:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0
```

Now, suppose I have a chain of measurements and need to detect an "anomalous" measurement (say, the matrix elements change radically in position and/or value). What I need to face this problem is to somehow convert a matrix to a single value and then perform anomaly detection on this chain of scalars. I thought about using the norm, but the posiotining information is lost, like I described above.

Comment: This is equivalent to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243590/bijection-from-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-rn, right?

Comment: It's not possible, this is simply due to the difference in dimension between the two spaces: $\mathbb R^{m \times n},$ the space of $m$ by $n$ matrices, is $mn-$dimensional, but the real numbers are only one-dimensional. Because of this, linear algebra says there can be no bijection between the two spaces.

Comment: @JoshuaWang I'm not sure, I'm no mathematician. From what I can tell, that question is looking for a way to go from R to R^N, but I believe this case is quite the opposite?

Comment: @StephenDonovan what if I serialize the matrix and make it R^(m*n x 1)? That is, make it a mn by 1 array?

Comment: My apologies, as I was looking more into the source of my statement I realized this only applies for *linear* maps, not maps in general. So it may be possible. However there is still the potential issue that you will lose information about the dimensions of your matrix if that's a concern. If the shape is known then the method laid out in the other answer should work just fine. (and I think there's probably a trick you can use to encode the size into the answer by using base $9$ and using $0$ as a special character)

Comment: Is there anything special about the matrices you're interested in? Nonnegative integer entries?

Comment: Well, I have two types of matrices. They're both square, symmetric matrices. One has got all binary values, while the other one has values from 0 to 2.

Comment: Are you aware of the computer concept of "hashing" a sequence of numbers? These are single values derived from a set of numbers that are designed to be sensitive to any changes in the set, either in value or arrangement.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Yes. However, I'm not familiar enough with the concept to figure out if very similar matrices would have similar hash outputs. Say, (2, 1, 0) = f1abd and (2, 0, 1) = f1bbd that would be fine. But I don't think that's quite the case? I may be wrong, though, will look into it.

Comment: You'll have to do some work deciding how to turn your matrices into a string of bytes, but just lazily treating them as text strings, crc16("(2, 1, 0)") = 2e37 and crc16("(2, 0, 1)") = 7e0b. (Using this [tool](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/crc16.html).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ (real $n\times m$ matrices) and $\mathbb{R}$ (the real line) are bijective as sets, but you don't even need that much. You just need a unique real number for each unique matrix, so an injective function. Bijectivity implies injectivity, so such a function must exist. (Whether or not it is practical is another issue.)

For your binary matrices, such a function is easy to construct. Let's go through an example.

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & c\\\ b & d\end{pmatrix}$$

Since the values are all $0$ or $1$, we can represent the matrix just as $a + 10b + 100c + 1000d$, and this gives straightforward unwrapping like:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow 1110$$

If other words, you just unwrap the matrix and place the digits next to each other.

If you don't have constant dimensions, you can unwrap the matrix and put a $2$ after each column. The above example would be:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow 1212120$$

Perhaps try to figure out the matrix corresponding to $2121212120$.

You may have more complicated matrices than this, but I think this example shows that you can write an injective function that maps a set of matrices to  scalar values.

(You have, however, asked about an XY problem, where you have issue X (matrix anomalies) and have idea Y (matrices as scalars) to solve X, and you've asked about Y instead of X. Your real question about matrix anomalies would be a great fit on Cross Validated where you originally posted this question. *That* is a statistical question, and a pretty good one, too. You may want to consider posting about that on Cross Validated.)

Comment: I agree with your injective function. But using  your idea (a+10b+100c+1000d), what if a =  10 and b = 1? You just lost positional information. I may be wrong here, but from what I can tell, the Frobenius norm itself is an injective function with a similar idea to yours. But like I said in the question, a difference in positioning may not be detected.

Comment: The particular injective function only applies to your binary matrices, so $a=10$ cannot happen. If you have a different input space (real matrices instead of binary matrices, for instance), then you would need a different injective function. However, the gist of an injective function is that, given a value to which an input point (or matrix) is mapped, there is a unique input point; no two input points map to the same output point. // I have my doubts that the Frobenius norm is injective (Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$ certainly isn't), but if it is, then you have a unique matrix per norm.

Comment: @eduardokapp It appears that that Frobenius norm is not injective. For instance, by my calculation, $\begin{pmatrix}-25 & 36\\\ -6 & 13\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}21 & -25\\\ 24 & 22\end{pmatrix}$ both have a Frobenius norm of $46.10857$, according to `matrixcalc::frobenius.norm` in `R`. Is that the same Frobenius norm that you get for those matrices?

Comment: You're right, Frobenius norm is not injective.

Answer (score 1):

(Note) The question was moved, but I think the OP found this answer useful. If elaboration or examples are desired then a supplied example form of matrix would be helpful.

You are trying to take many pieces of information and boil them down to a single numeric representation.

This is a good early question. Greats in the field engaged this question starting hundreds of years ago. There are still good things to consider here. Consider generative, before a decade ago it wouldn’t have been on the menu. Good answers here relate to physics and mathematics in many significant and important ways.

There are ways to do this.

- One could use a generative tool in machine learning to convert a scalar to a matrix. That tells you part of the problem though: it depends on what you’re trying to do with it.
- you could take a mean, arithmetic, geometric, harmonic, or other.
- You could compute the determinant
- You could compute a Norm, there are an infinite number of families of norms many of which have infinite members
- You could compute a statistical summary, such as the maximum, the minimum, a Quantile or interquantile, the variance or other moments, or one of infinite other statistics
- you could take the largest eigenvalue, or any statistical summary on the eigenvalues
- many other options

If you presume that it is a rotation, you could scale it, and then use geometric methods to extract the minimum angle of the rotation in a hyper sphere.

And this is the problem, the place were magic happens, because what you do to it has implicit assumptions. Without a clean articulation of what those assumptions are, it is impossible to get to the particular numeric value that is useful to you.